# Select features in statement CASE ELSE or CASE in QGIS 2.10.2

Tags: qgis, python, field-calculator, expression

I need to label only US states and canadian provincies [image]

Here is my attribute table
[image]

and my expression

[image]

Program show that is no error here, but it still don't work. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is this a label expression? Do you want to label with the text True or False?

Comment: No, it's general expression for features. And I want label US states and canadian provinces  names (Utah, Manitoba etc.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd set the `Show label` condition to something like:

```
"sr_adm0_a3" in ('USA', 'CAN')
```

[image]

You just need an expression that returns `True` for the countries you want to label and `false` for the others. In your case `ISO` looks promising.

Comment: I used attribute NAME_1 and your's suggested statement **in** ('USA', 'CAN') and it works! Thanks!